# How to see code coverage in Clion

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, code-coverage, clion

I need to be able to check how well my C++ code covered by unit test in critical places. I'm using Clion as IDE based on Cmake project structure (not sure if something else supported). Is there any ways to get code coverage info with Clion?

Comment: Search for it in [the CLion issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP). If the request doesn't exist yet, add one. Or create a plugin for it?

Comment: Maybe gcov will work. There is an article by Google on how they used it to get code coverage with gtest. https://testing.googleblog.com/2014/07/measuring-coverage-at-google.html
Basically you run gcov and it will tell you which lines of code executed how many times. So, you can run a test and check its coverage or run all the tests and find code that is not checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such feature in CLion for now. The feature request [exists](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-6214). Also we are unaware of any existing plugin for code coverage in CLion.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the latest *vanilla* versions of CLion (e.g. 2020.1.1) - no plugins required.

---

**DETAILS**

See [official doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/code-coverage-clion.html).

For example, on Linux (Fedora 31):

- Depending on compiler, ensure CLion picks the right toolchain:

  Even though `CMakeLists.txt` sets compiler for the build, it may
  disagree with the one chosen by IDE to show the coverage (something to be improved).
- Obviously, install necessary tools outside of IDE and ensure their versions match:

  ```
  sudo dnf install clang llvm # ...
  sudo dnf update
  ```

---

### gcc

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER cc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER c++)
set(COMPILE_FLAGS "--coverage")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "--coverage")
```

**File / Settings... / Build, Execution, Deployment / Toolchain**

[image: gcc]

---

### clang

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-fprofile-instr-generate")
```

**File / Settings... / Build, Execution, Deployment / Toolchain**

[image: clang]